# DataTable.SetField appears slow

Tags: c#, datatable

From performance analysis, this is very slow:

```
public static DataTable ReplaceNulls(DataTable table, double replacementValue = 0)
{
    int r = -1;
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        r++;
        foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Skip(1))
        {
            if ((object)row[col] == DBNull.Value)
            {
                row.SetField(col, replacementValue);
            }
        }

    }

    return table;
}
```

The issue is the SetField line. Can anyone suggest a faster approach?

Comment: What kind of value is being replaced? Can you provide an input/output example?

Comment: It is a double type